# Как передать в функцию вектор?

Tags: c++

Вот попытался передать у функцию вектор - код не работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>    
void f(const vector< vector<int> >int& k)
{
    for(int i=0;i<k.size();++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<k.size();++j)
        {
            cout<<k[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void main()
{
    int n=5;int m=5;
    vector < vector <int> >v(n,vector <int> (m));
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
        {
            v[i][j]=rand()%200-10;
        }
    }
    f(v);
}
```

Comment: -1, даже как-то не смешно.

Comment: так код то не работает

Comment: Это магнитные бури. Барометр показал, что не работает?

Comment: не барометр а компилятор

Comment: >не барометр а компилятор

@Роман Пономаренко вам довольно прозрачно пытаются намекнуть, что участники этого форума - люди, а не компиляторы, а потому не обязаны видеть ошибки компиляции невооруженным взглядом/ Если бы вы указали, какая конкретно у вас ошибка, то, вероятно, могли бы получить ответ гораздо быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Начни с простого:

1. Определи вектор, который хранит скалярные значения — минимальное изменение в программе: использовать `std::vector<int> v;` вместо `vector<int> v;` или `using namespace std;` (только для примера).
2. Можно использовать шаблон или alias'ы, чтобы не повторять ручками определение типа вектора: `template<class Container> void f(const Container& container);`. Если удалось передать простой вектор (1D), то можно к следующему шагу перейти.
3. Найти существующий или задать отдельный вопрос о том, как правильно использовать вектор для того, чтобы хранить 2D  данные.